# ReturnsAsync in Moq is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, moq

Here is my code

```
public interface IUserManager
{
  Task<int> PostUser(User user);
  IQueryable<User> GetUserById(long userId);
}

public class UserManager : IUserManager 
{
    public UserManager(DataContext context)
    {
        this.DataContext = context;
    }
    public async Task<int> PostUser(User user)
    {
        this.DataContext.User.Add(user);
        return await this.DataContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

   public IQueryable<User> GetUserById(long userId)
   {
      return this.DataContext.User
        .Where(userNotes => userNotes.UserId == userId).AsQueryable();
   }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class UserController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IUserManager userManager;

    public UserController()
    {
        this.userManager = new UserManager();
    }

    public UserController(IUserManager userManager)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<User> Get([FromODataUri]long userId)
    {
        return this.userManager.GetUserById(userId);
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Post(User user)
    {
        if (userNote == null || !ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return this.BuildErrorResponse(ResponseCodes.INVALID_MISSING_INPUTS);
        }

        if (this.userManager.PostUser(user).Result <= 0)
        {
            return this.BuildErrorResponse(ResponseCodes.USER_ADD_FAILED);
        }

        return this.BuildSuccessResponse<User>(ResponseCodes.USER_ADDED, user);
    }
}
```

Moq test:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest
{
    IUserManager userManagerMock;
    Mock<IUserManager> iUserManagerMock;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        //.. setup variables and mock data
        userManagerMock = new UserManager(ContextMock.Object);
        iUserManagerMock.Setup(u => u.PostUser(It.IsAny<User>()))
                .ReturnsAsync(1);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Post()
    {
        var controller = new UserController(userManagerMock); //userNotesManagerMock will have the mock data                                           //and mock methods setup
            var httpResponse = controller.Post(userPostMock); //userPostMock will have mock data to save

            //Assert.AreEqual(HttpResponseMessage, result);
    }
}
```

I wrote a post method as you'd see here. I've a Get method as well which is working perfectly with mocking data.

But when I debug through the Post, the data the following statement is always returns ZERO instead of 1, which I've set up in the ReturnsAsync.

```
this.userManager.PostUser(user).Result <= 0 //this always gives me zero
```

What's wrong with the post ? Am I doing anything wrong ?

Can anyone shed some light on this

---

**EDIT**

Here is the GET version of the Test method and setup

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Setup()
{
    //dummy data setup
    UserMock = new List<User>
    {
        new User { //blah blah properties }
    }.AsQueryable();

    //context setup
    dbSetUserMock = new Mock<IDbSet<User>>();
    dbSetUserMock.Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(UserMock.Provider);
    dbSetUserMock.Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(UserMock.Expression);
    dbSetUserMock.Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(UserMock.ElementType);
    dbSetUserMock.Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(UserMock.GetEnumerator());

    UserContextMock = new Mock<DataContext>();
    UserContextMock.Setup(s => s.User).Returns(dbSetUserMock.Object);

    //inject the context to manager
    UserManagerMock = new UserManager(UserContextMock.Object);

    iUserManagerMock = new Mock<IUserManager>();
    iUserManagerMock.Setup(notes => notes.PostUserNote(It.IsAny<User>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(1);
}

[TestMethod]
public void Get_User_Success()
{
    var controller = new UserController(UserManagerMock);
    var values = controller.Get(100);

    Assert.AreEqual(100, values.FirstOrDefault().UserId);
}
```

`Get_User_Success` works well now with the dummy data set and I'm able to pass the test without `iUserManagerMock` object. Reason being I want to execute the code inside of `GetUser()` method in Manager class.

And I've another question over here. As **I'm setting the expected result to be 1 in the ReturnAsync for Post action. How do I build a test method for failure case scenario as the return from the POST method will still be 1 for failure case ?**

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up the set up. If the method under test is the `UserController.Post` and you want to mock the `UserManager` via the `IUserManager` interface, then you don't need to new one up manually.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest {

    [TestMethod]
    public void UserController_Should_Post_User_Ok() {
        //Arrange
        var userPostMock = new User { UserId = 100 };
        var userManagerMock = new Mock<IUserManager>();
        userManagerMock.Setup(u => u.PostUser(It.IsAny<User>())).ReturnsAsync(1);
        var controller = new UserController(userManagerMock.Object);
        controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();

        //Act
        var httpResponse = controller.Post(userPostMock);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, httpResponse.StatusCode);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void UserController_Should_Post_User_Fail() {
        //Arrange
        var userPostMock = new User { UserId = 100 };
        var userManagerMock = new Mock<IUserManager>();
        userManagerMock.Setup(u => u.PostUser(It.IsAny<User>())).ReturnsAsync(0);//Replicating a failed post
        var controller = new UserController(userManagerMock.Object);
        controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();

        //Act
        var httpResponse = controller.Post(userPostMock);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, httpResponse.StatusCode);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void UserManager_Should_Get_User_Success() {
        //Arrange
        var userMock = new List<User>
        {
            new User (){ UserId=100 }
        }.AsQueryable();

        //context setup
        var dbSetUserMock = new Mock<IDbSet<User>>();
        dbSetUserMock.Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(userMock.Provider);
        dbSetUserMock.Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(userMock.Expression);
        dbSetUserMock.Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(userMock.ElementType);
        dbSetUserMock.Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(userMock.GetEnumerator());

        var userContextMock = new Mock<DataContext>();
        userContextMock.Setup(s => s.User).Returns(dbSetUserMock.Object);
        //inject the context to manager
        var userManagerMock = new UserManager(userContextMock.Object);

        //Act
        var values = userManagerMock.GetUserById(100);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(100, values.FirstOrDefault().UserId);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've used `userManagerMock` for calling `GET` and `iUserManagerMock` to call `POST`. If I mock the Get request with mock object which you've proposed, the test will not execute the logic inside of GET method in the manager class

Comment: Then you need to show more code as the answer was based on the code in your original post that targeted a specific problem. I believe the issue with the Get will also be directly related to how you set up your mocks. Unit tests are also suppose to be done in isolation. if you are sharing mocks between tests that you will run into that exact problem

Comment: @KarthikChintala show the `Get` Test to provide a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Ok you are mixing up what you really want to test. if the `UserManager` is the system under test then the test should focus on that system

Comment: Update the `IUserManeger` with the `GetUser` and also your original post also excluded the constructor of the class. It is difficult to help with only bits and pieces of the information.

Comment: Please see the updated controller, manager, interfaces along with constructors

Comment: Bear with me a while. I'm now confused. your have `this.DataContext.User` and `this.ControlDataContext.SaveChangesAsync` in `PostUser` then `ControlDataContext.UserNotes` in `GetUserById`

Comment: Apologies from my end. It is infact the datacontext that we use to get the data from entities. I'ved edited the code.

Comment: @KarthikChintala, I recreated a project using the code/updates you provided and the above unit tests both pass successfully.

Comment: Yes. They both will work. But how do I write a negative test case for POST action as it always expected to return 1 as we set that up in the initialize method. AND I need to walk through the logic inside of POST i.e., it has to step into the manager logic and return 1

Comment: Then create another test and set it up to return something other than 1. Remember you are the one in control of the test. If you look at the code in Post Action there are at least 3 places to make action return result other than ok. (`user==nul`l, `!ModelState.IsValid` and `this.userManager.PostUser(user).Result <= 0`.

Comment: I believe that's not the ideal thing to do.Thanks for all your effort Nkosi. Appreciate it. I'd like to give thumbs up again. But SO won't allow to do double up votes :(